# The use of comma in written English

Tags: punctuation

As a French native speaker who has to write a professional report in English, a question regarding the use of the comma crossed my mind. Here is an example of the type of sentence that might trouble me :

> The nature of the traffic demands, which are
>   represented by a finite number of stations on the Earth's surface, is
>   the source of two determining properties

Indeed, in French we use a lot of them and I was wondering whether for an English speaker the above commas feel unnecessary or not.

Comment: I read the sentence, and I am still wide awake. I can only conclude that no [comas](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coma) are involved in the sentence. The _commas_, on the other hand, both look perfectly fine to me, if perhaps not entirely necessary. If I had written the sentence, I would probably have put them there, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Loved it. And thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: The clause _which are ... surface_ is a nonrestrictive relative clause (i.e, it adds additional information, rather than restricting the noun it modifies). Nonrestrictive relative clauses are marked with intonation dips fore and aft which are represented in speech by commas. English commas always represent that [Mid-Low-High-Mid intonation contour](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html#curve), not unlike the Chinese 3rd tone in isolation, or the intonation used when counting: _38, 39, 40, 41, ..._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason to leave off/on commas in this kind of sentence is to make clear whether the "which" clause is a specifier or not. When I say

> The horse, which won the last race, still seems winded.

I am simply supplying additional information about the horse. On the other hand,

> The horse which won the last race still seems winded.

Means that I want to be specific about which horse I am speaking.

Comment: Thanks for that particularly relevant and clear answer. I was arguing with a coworker who turned out to be right, thanks for ruining my life, lol.